# Escaping a backstroke not working as expected

Tags: java

Why do I need to use four backstrokes to output one backstroke ?

```
    String str = "\"";
    str = str.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
System.out.println(str);
```

returns \"

```
but 

String str = str.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
System.out.println(str);
```

returns "

Answer (score 2):

`replaceAll` takes a regular expression for the first argument and a replacement string for the second - and you need to escape the backslash in the replacement string *as well as* in the Java code.

Unless you *need* regular expressions, just use `String.replace` instead, which doesn't use regular expressions:

```
String text = "a\\b\\c";
System.out.println(text); // Prints a\b\c
String replaced = text.replace("\\", "x");
System.out.println(replaced); // Prints axbxc
```

Personally I think it was a bit of a mistake for `String.replaceAll` to use regular expressions to start with (`replacePattern` would at least have made it more obvious), but it's too late to change now...

Comment: Strictly speaking, the second argument of `replaceAll` is not a regular expression, it's a [replacement string](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @axtavt: Good catch. I hadn't noticed it was the second argument causing problems, not the first. Will edit.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I've just noticed CharSequence implements String, did'nt think 'replace' would accept a String paramater.

Answer (score 0):

The String treats `\\` as `\`, unfortunately regex does as well so you need `\\\\` :|